# Quartz.NET vs JAMS vs?

Tags: .net, quartz.net, job-scheduling, quartz.net-2.0

We are currently using Quartz.NET 1.1.  (I see that Quartz.NET 2.0 was released a couple of weeks ago)

1.) Has anyone personally used both Quartz.NET and JAMS?  If so, which was the 'better' (easy to implement, easy to configure, reliable) of the two?

2.) Has anyone migrated from Quartz.NET 1.1 to Quartz.NET 2.0?  If so, how did that go?  Anything we should watch out for?

3.) Anyone using something other than Quartz.NET or JAMS that they like and would recommend?

Thank you!

Glen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use JAMS here and I am a big supporter.  We run 400+ unique processes using JAMS - some run every 5 minutes, others run daily and others run once a month, etc.  Has a bit of a learning curve to it but their support is top notch and they helped us every step of the way.  I am familiar with Quartz so I knew it was not going to be flexible enough for us right from the start so we did not even consider it.  Also, JAMS is not cheap - it runs in the thousands of dollars so you need to be prepared to spend $$$ if you are considering JAMS.

Answer (score 0):

1.) I have some experience with Quartz.NET and lots of experience with
    JAMS (I'm one of the developers). I can't say which is better
    without knowing more about what you need, they are not really the
    same thing. Quartz.NET is a framework that developers can use when
    building applications. JAMS is a commercial product that can be used
    right out of the box. It has an extensive .NET class library that
    developers can use when building their applications but, you don't
    have to start there. If you want to build you own job scheduler, start with Quartz.NET. If you want to buy a job scheduler, go with JAMS.

2.) Haven't done it.

3.) I like JAMS!